# Timeout para Upload file FTP em PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, php-7, ftp

Amigos, 
Estou tentando desenvolver o upload de arquivos para FTP por PHP.
Ao executa-lo o mesmo conecta com sucesso ao server FTP. Porém, a pagina fica carregando até um timeout e não termina de enviar o arquivo todo.

Segue código para utilizado. 
Alguma ideia para solucionar este caso ?

```
<?php
    $file = 'teste.txt';
    $remote_file = '/teste.txt';
    $ftp_server = "IPSERVER";
    $ftp_user_name = "user_name";
    $ftp_user_pass = "user_pass";

    // set up basic connection
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

    // login with username and password
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
    ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

    // upload a file
    if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
     echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
    } else {
     echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
    }

    // close the connection
    ftp_close($conn_id);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vinicius, temos duas situações. A primeira é a questão do tempo de execução setado no seu php.ini na diretiva max_execution_time. Pois esta se não alterada fica com padrão 30 segundos, o que é relativamente baixo, dependendo do arquivo a ser enviado.

Logo, você pode iniciar seu script com este código: `ini_set("max_execution_time",3000);`

Uma outra observação, também, que você pode alterar é no `ftp_connect($ftp_server);` Da maneira como você setou ele vem como padrão 90 segundos de conexão. Então considere aumentar o tempo na própria conexão assim: `ftp_connect($ftp_server,21,10);` o segundo parâmetro é a porta, obviamente, e o terceiro o tempo de tentativa de conexão. Considere alterar este último conforme necessidade.

Enfim, são algumas alternativas. Mas eu acredito que o a primeira solução irá resolver sua solicitação. Abraço, espero ter ajudado. Bom dia

Caso seu servidor seja em **Windows** será necessário configurar um servidor FTP no computador para que funcione o seu script. Como não foi mencionado para qual sistema operacional, assim como não temos versão. Vou colocar abaixo como configurar um servidor FTP para Windows Server 2003. Caso sua versão seja diferente poderá pesquisar sobre, porém, terá um norte:

> OBSERVAÇÃO: No Windows Server 2003, o Serviço FTP não é instalado por padrão ao instalar o IIS. Se você já instalou o IIS no computador, você deve usar a ferramenta Adicionar ou Remover Programas no Painel de Controle para instalar o Serviço FTP. 
>   
> Clique em Iniciar, aponte para Painel de Controle e clique em Adicionar ou Remover Programas.
>   
> Clique em Adicionar ou remover componentes do Windows.
>   
> Na lista Componentes, clique em Servidor de aplicativos, 
> clique em Serviços de Informação da Internet (IIS) (mas não marque ou desmarque a caixa de seleção) e clique em Detalhes.
>   
> Clique para marcar as seguintes caixas de seleção (se ainda não estiverem selecionadas):
>   
> Arquivos comuns
>   
> Serviço FTP (File Transfer Protocol)
>   
> Gerenciador do Internet Information Services
>   
> Clique para marcar as caixas de seleção próximas a qualquer outro serviço relacionado ao IIS ou subcomponente que você deseja instalar e clique em OK.
>   
> Clique em Avançar.
>   
> Ao ser solicitado, insira o CD-ROM do Windows Server 2003 na unidade de CD-ROM ou DVD-ROM do computador ou forneça o caminho para o local dos arquivos e 
> clique em OK.
>   
> Clique em Concluir.
>   
> IIS e o serviço FTP estão agora instalados. Você deve configurar o Serviço FTP antes de poder usá-lo.

Segue um exemplo, básico, porém prático para enviar o arquivo via ftp:

```
<?php
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' )
{
        //var_dump( $_FILES );//apenas para debug
        $servidor = '192.168.0.25';
        $caminho_absoluto = '';
        $arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];

        $con_id = ftp_connect($servidor) or die( 'Não conectou em: '.$servidor );

        ftp_login( $con_id, 'Leonardo', '1111' );

        echo 'Nome '.$arquivo['name'].'<br>';
        echo 'temp: '.$arquivo['tmp_name'];

        ftp_put( $con_id, $caminho_absoluto.$arquivo['name'], $arquivo['tmp_name'], FTP_BINARY );
}
?>
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="arquivo" />
            <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" />
        </form>
```

Comment: Leandro, obrigado pelo apoio. Com esta solução, consigo agora enviar para um FTP linux. Porém, tenho criado um FTP em servidor Windows e o problema de TimeOut persiste. Existe algum parâmetro para FTP criado em ambiente Windows?

Comment: Vou editar a resposta e irei acrescentar a solução para windows

Comment: editei, é sempre importante acrescentar na pergunta o máximo de informação possível para que possamos ajudá-lo com exatidão

Comment: Leandro, agradeço novamente, o servidor FTP no windows já esta criado e conseguimos acessa-lo via CMD ou até mesmo browser com as credencias. Acredito que o problema possa estar no Script. Saberia me informar se existe algum outro parâmetro para ser enviado ?

Comment: coloquei um exemplo prático, veja se te ajuda a resolver sua situação